# how to generate a matrix of random integers without duplicates in python

Tags: python

i need some help to create a matrix of dim (65, 8) where all elements are unique integers in range(522) in python

thanx!!

```
def bootstrap(x, num_samples, statistic, alpha):
"""Returns bootstrap estimate of 100.0*(1-alpha) CI for statistic."""
n = len(x)
y=len(x)**(1/3)
idx = np.random.randint(0, n, (num_samples, y)) #Return unique random integers from 0 to 520 in a martix with size num_samples X 520.
samples = x[idx]
stat = np.sort(statistic(samples, 1))
return (stat[int((alpha/2.0)*num_samples)],
        stat[int((1-alpha/2.0)*num_samples)])
```

Comment: Why it should be from range 0 to 521? This matrix should have exactly 520 elements. So do you want two of them to be missing?

Comment: no, you are right i want 520 elements..

Comment: Including `0`? So do you want numbers from range 0..519 or 1..520?

Comment: i want 1 to 520

Comment: `x = np.arange(1, 521), np.random.shuffle(x); x = x.reshape(65, 8)`

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion the easiest way would be to simply shuffle range of elements i.e.

```
x = numpy.arange(1, 521)
numpy.random.shuffle(x)
```

and then reshape it to matrix you want using [numpy.reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy.reshape)

```
x = numpy.reshape(x, (65,8))
```

Comment: You can do this with numpy's methods, they should be faster.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: Right. Edited:)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you a lot!
However, I think the right answer is:

```
x = np.arange(1, 521).reshape((65, 8))
np.random.shuffle(x)
```